# spring-data-neo4j v6: No converter found capable of converting from type [MyDTO] to type [org.neo4j.driver.Value]

Tags: spring, kotlin, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

**Situation**

I'm migrating a kotlin spring data neo4j application from `spring-data-neo4j` version `5.2.0.RELEASE` to version `6.0.11`.

The original application has several Repository interfaces with custom queries which take some DTO as a parameter, and use the various DTO fields to construct the query. All those types of queries currently fail with

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [MyDTO] to type [org.neo4j.driver.Value]
```

The [reference documentation for spring-data-neo4j v6](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#custom-queries) only provides examples where parameters passed to custom query methods of a `@Repository` interface are of the same type as the `@Node` class associated with that repository. The documentation does not explicitly state that only parameters of the Node class are allowed.

**Question**

Is there any way to pass an arbitrary DTO (not being a `@Node` class) to a custom query method in a `@Repository` interface in spring-data-neo4j **v6** like it was possible in v5?

## Code samples

**Example node entity**

```
@Node
data class MyEntity(
    @Id
    val attr1: String,
    val attr2: String,
    val attr3: String
)
```

**Example DTO**

```
data class MyDTO(
    val field1: String,
    val field2: String
)
```

**Example Repository interface**

```
@Repository
interface MyRepository : PagingAndSortingRepository<MyEntity, String> {

    // ConverterNotFoundException is thrown when this method is called
    @Query("MATCH (e:MyEntity {attr1: {0}.field1}) " +
           "CREATE (e)-[l:LINK]->(n:OtherEntity {attr2: {0}.field2))")
    fun doSomethingWithDto(dto: MyDTO)
}
```

## Solutions tried so far

**Annotate DTO as if it were a Node entity**

Based on the following found in the reference docs https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#custom-queries.parameters

> Mapped entities (everything with a @Node) passed as parameter to a
> function that is annotated with a custom query will be turned into a
> nested map.

```
@Node
data class MyDTO(
    @Id
    val field1: String,
    val field2: String
)
```

**Replace `{0}` with `$0` in custom query**

Based on the following found in the reference docs https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#custom-queries.parameters

> You do this exactly the same way as in a standard Cypher query issued
> in the Neo4j Browser or the Cypher-Shell, with the $ syntax (from
> Neo4j 4.0 on upwards, the old {foo} syntax for Cypher parameters has
> been removed from the database).

...

> [In the given listing] we are referring to the parameter by its name.
> You can also use $0 etc. instead.

```
@Repository
interface MyRepository : PagingAndSortingRepository<MyEntity, String> {
    
    // ConverterNotFoundException is thrown when this method is called
    @Query("MATCH (e:MyEntity {attr1: $0.field1}) " +
           "CREATE (e)-[l:LINK]->(n:OtherEntity {attr2: $0.field2))")
    fun doSomethingWithDto(dto: MyDTO)
}
```

## Details

- `spring-boot-starter`: `v2.4.10`
- `spring-data-neo4j`: `v6.0.12`
- `neo4j-java-driver`: `v4.1.4`
- `Neo4j server version`: `v3.5.29`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RTFM [Custom conversions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#custom.conversions.attribute.types) ...

Found the solution myself. Hopefully someone else may benefit from this as well.

## Solution

**Create a custom converter**

```
import mypackage.model.*
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.jacksonObjectMapper
import org.neo4j.driver.Value
import org.neo4j.driver.Values
import org.springframework.core.convert.TypeDescriptor
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.GenericConverter
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.GenericConverter.ConvertiblePair
import java.util.HashSet

class DtoToNeo4jValueConverter : GenericConverter {
    override fun getConvertibleTypes(): Set<ConvertiblePair>? {
        val convertiblePairs: MutableSet<ConvertiblePair> = HashSet()
        convertiblePairs.add(ConvertiblePair(MyDTO::class.java, Value::class.java))
        return convertiblePairs
    }

    override fun convert(source: Any?, sourceType: TypeDescriptor, targetType: TypeDescriptor?): Any? {
        return if (MyDTO::class.java.isAssignableFrom(sourceType.type)) {
            // generic way of converting an object into a map
            val dataclassAsMap = jacksonObjectMapper().convertValue(source as MyDTO, object :
                    TypeReference<Map<String, Any>>() {})
            Values.value(dataclassAsMap)
        } else null
    }
}
```

**Register custom converter in config**

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.convert.Neo4jConversions
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.GenericConverter
import java.util.*


@Configuration
class MyNeo4jConfig {
    @Bean
    override fun neo4jConversions(): Neo4jConversions? {
        val additionalConverters: Set<GenericConverter?> = Collections.singleton(DtoToNeo4jValueConverter())
        return Neo4jConversions(additionalConverters)
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have a Java version of the code. I specifically need it for convert() method.

Answer (score 0):

It's ridiculous that the framework would force you to write a custom converter for this. I made a @Transient object in my overridden User class for a limited set of update-able user profile fields, and I'm encountering the same error. I guess I will just have to break up the object into its component String fields in the method params to get around this problem. What a mess.

```
@Query("MATCH (u:User) WHERE u.username = :#{#username} SET u.firstName = :#{#up.firstName},u.lastName = :#{#up.firstName},u.intro = :#{#up.intro} RETURN u")
Mono<User> update(@Param("username") String username,@Param("up") UserProfile up);
```

No converter found capable of converting from type [...UserProfile] to type [org.neo4j.driver.Value]